# Two Mirrors Facing Each Other

Tags: materials, reflection

I have two planes with a mirror-material facing each other.
Anybody know how I can get the reflection in the distance to display properly, rather than have it black?

Rendering in Cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into the *Render panel > Light Paths > Max Bounces* > Increase the *Glossy* value:

[image]